# Connecting multiple conditions using postfix code completion in Intelij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intelij Idea and want to join multiple conditionals in one `if` statement. For example, this is what I do if I have to check if a list is not null or empty (this is just an example):

```
list.notnull
```

This translates to:

```
if (list != null) {

}
```

Now inside the `if` block I check if the list is not empty:

```
if (list != null) {
    list.isEmpty().if
}
```

which in turn translates to:

```
if (list != null) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {

    }
}
```

Now I go to the start of first `if` and press `Alt + RETURN` to select `Merge ifs into one` and this results into:

```
if (list != null && list.empty()) {

}
```

I know the condition makes no sense at all but what I want to know if there is a way to avoid these many steps for joining multiple `if` conditions? Something along the lines:

```
list.notNull.and.list.isEmpty().not.if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply join if's you can use `Join Lines` action (`control-shift-j`).

Also, you can start by typing your conditions, then type `.if` and press `TAB`. Your conditions will be wrapped with `if`:
`list != null && list.empty().if`

Also, you can set up your own postfix completions in `Preferences | Editor | General | Postfix Completion`

[image]